# Text field for basic non domain types in 'has many' of grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

The domain class is:

```
 package com.sample

 class Person {
   String id
   String name
   Integer age
   Address address
     static hasMany = [pets:Pet, children : String]

     static mapWith = "mongo"
     static constraints = {
            address nullable:true
     }
 }
```

This is the create page of the app :

[image: create page of grails app]

Can someone tell me how I can get a text field for the field 'children'(encircled in red)
Im using auto generated views

Comment: hasMany is for references to other tables. Are you sure you want to put String there.

Comment: Then how should I represent a List<String> in groovy

Comment: Assuming that you have domain object for Children similar to Pet. I was hoping you could have written similar to Pets.

Comment: What if I don't have a domain object similar to Pet and I want to implement List<String> ? Is creating the domain object the only way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove children from hasMany constraint and put it just like other variables.Then change the tag in gsp file from  to